# C++: Convert Macro based Property System to use templates

Tags: c++, design-patterns, templates, properties, macros

I've already implemented, using macros, a C++ property system that satisfied the following requirements:

- Property can be referenced using a integeral key
- Property can be accessed via a generic Set/Get
- Properties (and property keys) must be inheritable
- Properties can be registered with getters/setters

and is implemented as follows

- Each property belongs to a class
- Each property is 'declared' with a key unique to it's inheritance chain. (Implemented using a rather clever __ COUNTER __ hack). It has the following characteristic

  - A root class (no parents) start numbering its properties from 0
  - A child class will start numbering its properties from the parent's last id + 1

---

```
class A
{    
    static const unsigned int Property_0 = GET_KEY_MACRO; //expands to 0
    static const unsigned int Property_1 = GET_KEY_MACRO; //expands to 1     
};
class B : public A
{    
    static const unsigned int Property_0 = GET_KEY_MACRO(A); //expands to 2
    //and so forth    
};
class C : public A
{
     static const unsigned int Property_0 = GET_KEY_MACRO(A); //expands to 2. different inheritance chain
};
```

---

- Other code can refer to the property using the static constant id.

---

```
objectinstance.SetValue(C::Property_0, 5)
```

---

- Each property is 'registered' by using a macro that expands to a virtual method. The macro currently allows for a property type, a getter, and a setter to be registered

---

```
BEGIN_PROPERTIES
    REG_PROP(Property_0, int)
    REG_PROP_G(Property_1, int, getterFunc)
    ...
END_PROPERTIES

//expands to 

virtual void registerProperties()
{
    register(blah, blah, ...)
}
```

---

- SetValue/GetValue that takes a property key and does some background magic to set/get it(already implemented)

Can anyone think of template based approach that's equivalent/simpler to the above system?

Note: This property system is to designed for remote RPCish calls as well as fast local access.

Comment: `__COUNTER__` is a name reserved for the implementation, and with such a simple name might very well be taken. Stick to _cOUNTER_ or _jAMESZHAO00_COUNTER (etc) to be safe.

Comment: __ COUNTER __ is a predefined macro variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a classic game property system so I'm going to recommend you read this [Gamasutra](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3683/a_templated_c_attribute_library_.php) article about a good system that doesn't require too much gunk around your code. Also have a look at [boost.fusion](http://spirit.sourceforge.net/dl_more/fusion_v2/libs/fusion/doc/html/index.html) and see if it can't help you.

What follows is my opinion and can be ignored for the sake of the question:

That said I'm not really sure what you'd gain by using templates. Is it just that "Macros Are Bad"?

Having worked with a bunch of these systems I've come to the conclusion that you're often solving the wrong problem by adding a property system. If you can, consider using a language like C# where properties are first-class language feature.

Comment: I tried mono/C#. Had to ditch it because of its non-incremental GC was hanging randomly.

Comment: My first implementation used strings as keys, and I had no problems. I switched the keys to ints for better performance.

Comment: I see. Did you try real C#? The Visual Studio Express editions are "free": http://www.microsoft.com/express/product/. That said I have no experience handling managed/unmanaged code in the one project.

Comment: This has to run on Linux unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Even if it's possible, you'll probably find that template metaprogramming is functional, meaning global state like *COUNTER* won't be available.  That suggests to me that the "UI" for this compile-time library could be ugly.  You'll probably also end up with worse compile times.

Using templates to chain together a sequence of ids functionally you'd get a typelist of single-property-of-type structures.